# how i can show my layout(xml file) when i open any android app?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-contentprovider

I'am new here > i want some help to build some code but i can't find any code ..>
i have some project i must done it > so i hear about this website which is giving us helps by professional developer and programmer .My Question :how i can show my layout(xml file) when i open any android app ?? >> i mean how i can call my activity when i open any android application or replace activities between my app and any apps in android device.... so when i open any android application in my device the result will be show my layout(xml file) ... so how i can do it ??

i wish that anyone answer me ....
and i will be thankful
I'am called : (amjad)

Comment: i don't you get actually ? what you want ?

Answer (score 2):

Actually assuming you have 1 activity name as MainActivity in src folder of eclipse
and xml file name as main in res->layout

then you have to add following code in your activity

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

By this you can use contain in xml file

Answer (score 2):

dude check this guy :) he has a beginners tutorial series with index, so you can check any certain topic ,or follow one after another to save you time in learning best of luck ;) 
http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to below link (basic tutorial for Android from Android/Google team): 
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html

Update:
I see that you have edited the question with more details. But, I am not sure if there is a way to call your app automatically when some one starts another App in the device unless it's a system level app. What you can do is provide one public intent to be called by any other apps  and then at load time, the app calls your intent and hence can display your layout/xml.